# Is it possible to increase the timeout for Google Cloud Datastore requests?

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

We are developping an application that uses the Google Cloud Datastore, important detail: it's not an gae application!
Everything works fine for normal usage. We designed a test that fetches over 30000 records but when we tried to run the test we got the following error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

We found that a Timeout Exception occurs after 30 seconds, so this explains the error.
I have two questions:

- Is there a way to increase this timeout?
- Is it possible to use pagination to query the datastore? We found when you have an aep application you can use the cursor, but our application isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cursors in the exact same way as a GAE app using Datastore. Take a look at [this page for info](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#Datastore_Query_cursors).

In particular, the `ResultQueryBatch` object has an `.getEndCursor()` method which you can then use when you reissue a `Query` with `setStartCursor(...)`. Here's a code snippet from the page above:

```
Query q = ...
if (response.getBatch().getMoreResults() == QueryResultBatch.MoreResultsType.NOT_FINISHED) {
  ByteString endCursor = response.getBatch().getEndCursor();
  q.setStartCursor(endCursor);
  // reissue the query to get more results...
}
```

You should definitely use cursors to ensure that you get all your results. The rpc has additional constraints to time like total rpc size, so you shouldn't depend on a single rpc answering your entire query.

Comment: Could you provide me with more information on "not depending on a single rpc answering your entire query"? Like how can I use more then one? A reference would be fine!